# Scrollable Echo DB Table with Fix header

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I'm trying to make a scrollable table with fix header. This works well if the data is entered to HTML, but when I try to echo content of my database to the table, the scroll bar messes up and my header is no longer fixed. As seen in the photo, the scroll bar is on each table entry. I've tried .div wrapping up the table body as some did but it doesn't work.

[image]

```css
 body{
 background: lightblue;
} 

#tble th {
    text-align: left;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}

table{
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 350px;
}

tbody{
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

th {
  width: 75px;
}

td { 
  width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<body>
<table align="center" id="tble">
  <thead>
  <th style="text-align: center">ID</th>
  <th style="text-align: center">Username</th>
  <th style="text-align: center">Rights</th>
  <th style="text-align: center">Age</th>
  </thead>

  <tbody>   
  <tr>
  <?php
   $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "account");
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM account.log WHERE rights IN ('Admin','User')", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT) or die(mysql_error());
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) {
   ?>
    <td style="text-align: center"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
    <td style="text-align: center"><?php echo $row['user']; ?></td>
    <td style="text-align: center"><?php echo $row['rights']; ?></td>
    <td style="text-align: center"><?php echo $row['age']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
<?php 
}
?>
</body>
</table>
```

Is there something I missed? Hoping someone could point me to the right direction.

Comment: Dunno if it will help but your code will make many `</tr>` tags but only one `<tr>`  https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp\

Comment: put your **<tr>** tag inside the while loop of your php code, as @Edgarth said, you are generating mulitple **</tr>** tag with only one **<tr>** opening tag

Comment: Hi @Edgarth - I'll try that. I'll revert back. Thanks!

Comment: @Edgarth - sadly it made no difference. Still, thanks!

Comment: have you tried adding overflow-y to the <table> tag instead of your <tbody> tag in your css? whats the result?

Comment: @David try adding `css` tag to your question, maybe `overflow-y: scroll;` not working correctly, hah like Programing Newb said

Comment: @ProgrammingNewb - I did that earlier and actually it fixes to a single scroll bar, however the header moves together with the data when when scrolling. Do you have an idea how can I fix the header if I'll tag the overflow to the table instead? Thanks!

Comment: @Edgarth - probably? =D I've tagged it.

Comment: i wonder if adding element to the header**thead{ position: fixed --other code--} will fix the problem

Comment: I've never encountered adding a scrollbar directly to the table in html before so this is a first for me, I generally just scroll the page when i want to view elements in my table, so this is a new experience for me, so I upvoted XD

Comment: @ProgrammingNewb - couldn't agree more. lol. Hopefully someone could pass by to point us to the right direction.

Comment: Did you try adding the <thead> position:fixed comment before to your code??

Comment: @ProgrammingNewb - I just tried it and it sort of works. The header itself it thrown out of the table and you can reposition it on top. Might be prone to misalignment? Good one, bro! Thanks!

Comment: No probs, with CSS it's a lot of tinkering before it actually works, but glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

<html lang="en">
<body>
<table align="center" id="tble">
  <thead>
  <th style="text-align: center">ID</th>
  <th style="text-align: center">Username</th>
  <th style="text-align: center">Rights</th>
  <th style="text-align: center">Age</th>
  </thead>

  <tbody>   
  <tr>//move this from here
  <?php
   $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "account");
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM account.log WHERE rights IN ('Admin','User')", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT) or die(mysql_error());
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) {
   ?>
    <tr> //to here
    <td style="text-align: center"><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
    <td style="text-align: center"><?php echo $row['user']; ?></td>
    <td style="text-align: center"><?php echo $row['rights']; ?></td>
    <td style="text-align: center"><?php echo $row['age']; ?></td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
<?php 
}
?>
</body>
</table>
```

Comment: Hello @Programming Newb - I've tried and it seems nothing has changed. After I reposition the <tr> tag.